# 'pageTitleClass' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-server-2008

This is my class and into the App_Code pageTitle.cs
I am getting Compilation Error...

```
Line 4:  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
Line 5:  <head runat="server">
Line 6:      <title><% pageTitleClass pagetitle = new pageTitleClass(); Response.Write(pagetitle.siteTitle); %></title>
Line 7:      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
Line 8:     <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
Source File: d:\inetpub\turkeco.com\www\beta\default.aspx    Line: 6 




 d:\inetpub\turkeco.com\www\beta\default.aspx(6,46): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'pageTitleClass' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

 d:\inetpub\turkeco.com\www\beta\default.aspx(6,15): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'pageTitleClass' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)




    public class pageTitleClass
{
    public string siteTitle = "PageTitle";
}
```

It is worked on localhost but My hosting company update server to Windows Server 2008 and It's giving error. Is this problem  because of me or hosting company and How can i fix it ?

Comment: What's on lines 1-3? What namespace is `pageTitleClass` in (note that `pageTitleClass` violates the naming guide, class names should be PascalCase)? The error basically tells you what is wrong: "are you missing a using directive?"

Comment: Don't have the namespace... Don't show on error line.  If show, i write in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a very odd way of setting the Title of the Page. The normal way to do it is in the Code Behind class. In the Page_Load event set `this.Title = "Page Title";`.

Otherwise, don't have enough information to help you. Apparently you're not getting a compilation error any more

> It is worked but ...

... but you give no details of the error you're getting on W2K8. Without that, there's not a lot anyone can tell you....

Comment: The error is there in the midst of the code block; I've cleaned up the layout of the question but it needs to be reviewed before it is visible. It is indeed an odd way to do things; there are plenty of other ways this code could be improved (like the name `pageTitleClass`).

Comment: I'd suggest you don't do it that way; do it the way I suggested via the .Title property in code behind.

Comment: Windows Server 2003 -> 2008. [look this photo](http://i.imgur.com/BePteq4.png) and 
Working on local?